# Broadcast Receiver with Media button

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to get a broadcast receiver to run when the user presses the volume down button.
It works in the main but for a broadcast receiver it is different.
Note: Excuse my English, I am Peruvian and I do not speak English.

Comment: What do you mean by "it works in the main"?

Comment: using keyEvent in the main.
the problem is in the manifest, in the Receiver
` <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" > 
       </action>
</intent-filter>`